# SVG-файл clip-path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, clip-path

Я пытаюсь применить clip-path с моим файлом SVG к изображению. Я нашел пример, это именно то, что я пытаюсь сделать, но я не могу реализовать свой объект таким же образом. Также у меня есть файл svg, path  который я использую,  чтобы сделать что-то подобное.

```css
img {
  clip-path: url(#svgClip);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
```

```html
  <img src="https://media-cdn.t24.com.tr/media/library/2021/07/1627040373809-100496736-steve-jobs-march-2011-getty.jpg" alt="Photographer in a market." />
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <clipPath id="svgClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M0.75815095,0.0579477769 C0.879893708,0.187288937 0.902165272,0.677587654 0.799370955,0.785996249 C0.627963035,0.966765889 0.26163708,0.91434951 0.111342491,0.755791573 C-0.0332137967,0.603287436 -0.035795248,0.382887577 0.0965066612,0.173955315 C0.200239457,0.0101396315 0.648923894,-0.0580965318 0.75815095,0.0579477769 Z"></path>
    </clipPath>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Это мой [файл SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/dgs.svg)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="500" height="500">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="_clipPath_83N3rlbeDk9CuuExdeWmYg5Uk1iUKzVX">
     <rect width="1000" height="1000"/></clipPath>
     </defs>
     <g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_83N3rlbeDk9CuuExdeWmYg5Uk1iUKzVX)">
       <path d="M 112 199.809 L 636.962 125.131 C 733.54 111.392 823.103 178.647 836.842 275.226 L 911.52 800.191 L 386.558 874.869 C 289.98 888.608 200.417 821.353 186.678 724.774 L 112 199.809 Z" style="stroke:none;fill:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;"/>
       </g>
      </svg>
```

Когда я заменяю в примере выше в `clip-path` на свой `path` ничего не получается.

Как я могу правильно реализовать свой файл svg в этом примере?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Clip Path SVG file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70864383/7394871) от участника  [@phzdjz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10032066/phzdjz).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/70864383/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Основная проблема заключается в относительном положении изображения и `clipPath`. Изображение не попадает в зону действия clipPath, поэтому нет эффекта обрезки изображения.
Чтобы исправить это, я поместил изображение и path из вашего файла svg, который будет действовать как `clip-path`, в один файл  svg.
Но всё равно нужно дополнительное позиционирование, чтобы портрет был по центру.

***Обратите внимание*** - белый контур на изображении, это зона действия `clip-path`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="800" height="450" viewBox="0 0 1600 900" >  
         
  <image  xlink:href="https://media-cdn.t24.com.tr/media/library/2021/07/1627040373809-100496736-steve-jobs-march-2011-getty.jpg" alt="Photographer in a market." width="100%" height="100%"  />

     <path fill="none" stroke="white"  d="M 112 199.809 L 636.962 125.131 C 733.54 111.392 823.103 178.647 836.842 275.226 L 911.52 800.191 L 386.558 874.869 C 289.98 888.608 200.417 821.353 186.678 724.774 L 112 199.809 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Чтобы центрировать кадр, я использовал команду преобразования `transform="translate(140,-30)"`

```html
 <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="800" height="450" viewBox="0 0 1600 900" >  
         
  <image  xlink:href="https://media-cdn.t24.com.tr/media/library/2021/07/1627040373809-100496736-steve-jobs-march-2011-getty.jpg" alt="Photographer in a market." width="100%" height="100%"  />

     <path transform="translate(140,-30)" fill="none" stroke="white"  d="M 112 199.809 L 636.962 125.131 C 733.54 111.392 823.103 178.647 836.842 275.226 L 911.52 800.191 L 386.558 874.869 C 289.98 888.608 200.417 821.353 186.678 724.774 L 112 199.809 Z"/>
</svg>
```

### SVG clipPath syntax

```css
.container {
width:80vw;
height:80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 1600 900">  
<defs>
       <clipPath id="cP">
        <path fill="none" stroke="white" transform="translate(140,-30)" d="M 112 199.809 L 636.962 125.131 C 733.54 111.392 823.103 178.647 836.842 275.226 L 911.52 800.191 L 386.558 874.869 C 289.98 888.608 200.417 821.353 186.678 724.774 L 112 199.809 Z"/>
      </clipPath>   
</defs>
  <image clip-path="url(#cP)" xlink:href="https://media-cdn.t24.com.tr/media/library/2021/07/1627040373809-100496736-steve-jobs-march-2011-getty.jpg" alt="Photographer in a market." width="100%" height="100%"  />
</svg>
</div>
```

### CSS clip-path syntax

Поскольку размер фотографии намного больше размера клипа, мне пришлось применить преобразование уменьшения размера изображения.

Откройте окно на полный просмотр

```css
img {
 clip-path:url(#cP); 
transform: scale(0.5);

 }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f32cF.jpg" />  
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="0" height="0"  >  
<defs>
       <clipPath id="cP">
        <path fill="none"  transform="translate(140,-30)" d="M 112 199.809 L 636.962 125.131 C 733.54 111.392 823.103 178.647 836.842 275.226 L 911.52 800.191 L 386.558 874.869 C 289.98 888.608 200.417 821.353 186.678 724.774 L 112 199.809 Z"/>
      </clipPath>   
</defs>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70867676/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Для легкого повторного использования clip-path я рекомендую следующие шаги:

1. обрежьте свой путь до его фактических границ
2. Масштабируйте путь клипа, чтобы он соответствовал [bBox 1x1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055893/complex-svg-clip-path-responsive#48075809).
3. Создайте класс переноса изображения css, применяя начальное соотношение сторон clip-path к изображению.

### пример обрезанного clip-path

```css
.img-wrp {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.img-wrp-aspect {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/** добавить псевдоэлемент соотношения сторон: в соответствии с элементом clip-path **/
.img-wrp-aspect:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: var(--aspectRatPad);
}
.img-clipped {
  clip-path: url(#clipPath);
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.svgHidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrp img-wrp-aspect" style="--aspectRatPad:94.219%">
  <img class="img-clipped" style="clip-path: url(#clipPath); object-position:50% 0%" src="https://media-cdn.t24.com.tr/media/library/2021/07/1627040373809-100496736-steve-jobs-march-2011-getty.jpg" alt="Photographer in a market." />
</div>

<div class="img-wrp img-wrp-aspect" style="--aspectRatPad:94.219%">
  <img class="img-clipped" style="clip-path: url(#clipPath); object-position:20% 0%" src="https://media-cdn.t24.com.tr/media/library/2021/07/1627040373809-100496736-steve-jobs-march-2011-getty.jpg" alt="Photographer in a market." />
</div>

<!-- hidden clip-path svg -->
<!-- 1. cropped and scaled down to 1x1 units -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="svgHidden" aria-hidden="true">
  <clipPath id="clipPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M0 0.101l0.657-0.099c0.12-0.018 0.232 0.071 0.25 0.199l0.093 0.697l-0.657 0.099c-0.12 0.018-0.232-0.071-0.25-0.199l-0.093-0.697z" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
<p>Вы можете изменить положение изображения, изменив <strong>object-position</strong> attribute</p>
```

Чтобы подогнать изображение под размеры обрезанных фреймов, вы можете использовать `object-fit:auto` (на самом деле, как ваш оригинальный css:

```
.img-clipped {
  clip-path: url(#clipPath);
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Ширина макета изображения контролируется оберткой

### Как получить обрезанный clip-path?

1. Откройте и нарисуйте его в приложении для векторной графики, таком как AI, Inkscape, Figma и т.д. (Честно говоря, я думаю, что эту опцию часто упускают из виду)
2. используйте помощник js, например: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/JjORMbK) (просто вставьте свой путь и установите флажок «clipPath».
3. Используйте отличный помощник [Yoksel по clip-path](https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/). По умолчанию он ничего не обрезает, но есть также опция **"Remove offset"**.

Примечание переводчика: Оба генератора переводят абсолютные координаты в цифры в долях единицы (от 0 до 1)
Это нужно при `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

### Решение css path()

(Теоретически) вы также можете определить clip-path непосредственно в css, например так ([пример MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)):

`clip-path: path('M 0 200 L 0,75 A 5,5 0,0,1 150,75 L 200 200 z');`

К сожалению, возможности css (псевдо svg) еще не соответствуют путям отсечения на основе svg — это, скорее всего, изменится в будущих версиях браузера, в которых будут представлены более сложные концепции масштабирования/подгонки пути.

Тем не менее, [библиотека pathfit @ccprog](https://github.com/ccprog/pathfit) может быть интересна для исправления вышеупомянутых недостатков css path().

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70990961/7394871) от участника  [@herrstrietzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15015675/herrstrietzel).</sub>